# Htaccess crashing my site

Tags: .htaccess

Having a problem with adding a .`htaccess` to one of my sites, whether I leave it blank or use code from a working `.htaccess` from another site I'm getting the same error 500 and my website goes down.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where the problem may be? Seems to be the two differences between my sites working with `.htaccess` and the ones not - Do you need a `public_html` to have a `.htaccess`? Or is it to do with hosting? Or something else?

Comment: have you checked your error logs?

Comment: The http servers error log file _always_ is the first place to look to. That is where you can actually _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: Post the .htaccess here, as some will be able to spot errors-- along with the intended/expected function of the config in .htaccess. But the Apache error log is indeed the place to start.

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That is error in browser which is of no use here. You need to check Apache error.log and see the message you're getting for 500 in browser.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea where apache error log would be?